# Is there an example that n linearly independent elements don't span to the whole space of dimension n?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

If $F$ is a field, and $a_1,a_2,...a_n$ are linearly independent elements in $F^n$, is this possible that span($a_1,a_2,...a_n$) is a proper subspace of $F^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The span of any $n$ linearly independent elements in an $n$-dimensional vector space is necessarily equal to the entire vector space. To show this, take any $x \in F^n$. Then the list
$$x,a_1,\ldots,a_n$$
is linearly dependent (by definition of dimension), so there exist $c,c_1,\ldots,c_n$, not all 0, so that
$$cx + c_1a_1 + \cdots + c_na_n = 0.$$
Since $c \neq 0$ (if it were 0, then that would imply the linear dependence of the $a_i$), we can write
$$x = -\frac{c_1}{c}a_1 - \cdots - \frac{c_n}{c}a_n,$$
so $x$ is in the span of the $a_i$. The fact that $F^n$ is $n$-dimensional is a consequence of the Steinitz Exchange Lemma.